# Why did Everything threaten me with a copyright violation?

Tags: everything

While floating around in space as a Super Star Cluster, [I had a very strange warning screen appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC2d3.jpg).

> STOP
>   EXTREME COPYRIGHT VIOLATION DETECTED
>
> THIS MATERIAL IS COPYRIGHT **ME, NOT YOU**. DON'T YOU **DARE** COPY **ANY** OF IT. IF YOU SO MUCH AS SHARE ONE FRAME OF THIS VIDEO GAME ON THE INTERNET YOU'LL BE IN JAIL **FOR THE REST OF YOUR ALREADY MISERABLE LIFE**. IS THAT WHAT YOU WANT? HOW PROUD WOULD YOUR **PARENTS** BE IF I CALLED THEM UP AND **TOLD THEM** YOU WERE SQUATTING IN MY HOUSE, EATING MY FOOD AND TRYING TO SET FIRE TO **MY CHILDREN?** WHEN I'M DONE WITH YOU YOU'LL NEVER SHARE ANYTHING AGAIN, EXCEPT FOR THE **PRISON CELL** YOU'LL BE SHARING **WITH ME**, WHERE I'LL READ YOU **COPYRIGHT LAW** UNTIL YOUR SKELETON CRAWLS OUT OF YOUR SKIN AND CREATES A **SMALL HUT** WITH IT, WHICH I'LL LIVE IN FOR **AS LONG AS IT TAKES** UNTIL YOU LEARN YOUR LESSON.

I have no idea what this screen actually means or what caused it to appear. I hadn't taken any screenshots, except for screenshotting the warning screen itself.

Why did Everything warn me that a copyright violation was detected?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Screens like this show up when you have too many objects spawned in your game to the point where it would affect performance. It doesn't actually mean anything, but it's the way the game handles maintaining a relatively consistent frame rate. If it gets too close to slowing down/freezing up, it simply destroys things in the background and displays a "disaster". These can be turned off in the Settings menu.

From [the Everything FAQ](http://www.everything-game.com/faq/):

> **I am hearing loud noises and seeing crazy images**
>
> The game will automatically optimize itself if it is pushed to very low frame rates. It does this by creating Disasters which can be switched off under Settings. If you are seeing these very frequently, you may be playing the game below minimum spec and require a faster machine.

Comment: Do these only appear at the largest scale?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro definitely not. It's happened when I was "regular" size (person-sized)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Also happened to me within the first few minutes of starting my first game (mountain-lion-sized)